# How to count similar results in several columns in Libre Office Calc?

Tags: libreoffice

On LibreOffice Calc, I have seven columns filled with any one of the non-numerical values *a*, *b* or *c*. For each line, I want to count how many times the *a* value has been entered.

How can I do that? I couldn't find a way to do that with the Data Pilot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the seven columns are A:G and the first row is 1:

In H1 enter
`=COUNTIF(A1:G1;"=a")`

and copy down.

*Credits to John V at [www.oooforum.org](http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.phtml?p=438980#438980).*